# How to generate sql concat strings dynamically in shell script

Tags: shell

Im trying to generate sql statement and in sql statement Im concatenating strings in the following format in shell script

```
select concat(source_sys,concat('_',concat(company_code,concat('_',concat(ml_document,concat('_',ml_document_item)))))) as KeyColumn, * from $table where $cond_column_name=$cond_column_value
```

How can I build the concat string dynamically with N number of strings. Lets say If I have strings `source_sys,company_code,ml_document,ml_document_item` then the concat statement will be `concat(source_sys,concat('_',concat(company_code,concat('_',concat(ml_document,concat('_',ml_document_item))))))`

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear why you must use `concat`. If you have sql access in your shell, you can simply store each piece of the string as a variable and then concatenate all through assignment, e.g. `string="$var1 $var2 $var3 ..."`. Then you could simply do whatever you need with the combined string (send it back to the db in an update query, output it, etc..)  What is your ultimate use for the combined string?

Comment: well Im not using sql access in shell. Im building the statement to use it in sqoop command which requires a concatenation of strings.